# FragmentActivity error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

Hi i am creating an activity with 4 selection in `drawerlayout`. Once the user select, a fragment will appear.

First I use `Fragment` and it run but when I try to convert it into `FragmentActivity`, i got an error on this line -

> fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container,
>   fragment).commit();

```
 private void selectItemFragment(int position){

    FragmentActivity fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentDoctor();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentHospital();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentPharmacy();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentClinic();
            break;
    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

FRAGMENT DOCTOR

```
public class FragmentDoctor extends FragmentActivity {


GoogleMap map;
public FragmentDoctor() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_doctor);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (map == null){

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (map != null){
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
String[]titles = {"Doctor", "Hospital", "Pharmacy", "Specialty Clinic"};
private CharSequence mTitle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private Toolbar topToolBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = " ";

    topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
    topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
    topToolBar.setLogoDescription(" ");

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


    List<ItemObject> listViewItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObject("Doctor", R.drawable.icon_doctor));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObject("Hospital", R.drawable.icon_hospital));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObject("Pharmacy", R.drawable.icon_pharmacy));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObject("Specialty Clinic", R.drawable.icon_clinic));

    //FIRST FRAGMENT AFTER SPLASH SCREEN
    selectItemFragment(0);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, listViewItems));

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selectItemFragment(position);
        }
    });
}

private void selectItemFragment(int position){

    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentDoctor();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentHospital();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentPharmacy();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentClinic();
            break;
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(null);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

IMPORTS IN MAIN ACTIVITY

```
android.content.res.Configuration;
android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
android.os.Bundle;
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
android.view.LayoutInflater;
android.view.Menu;
android.view.MenuItem;
android.view.View;
android.widget.ListView;
```

Comment: in (R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment), there's a red line in fragment and it says wrong 2nd argument type. found android.support.v4.app.fragmentactivity required android.support.v4.app.fragment

Comment: but i already import android.support.v4.app.fragmentactivity to the fragments in the case

Comment: A FragmentActivity is not a Fragment.

Comment: @Gem Ubaldo : Can I have code for this class `FragmentDoctor`?

Comment: @phxhawke is it possible in drawerlayout that instead of fragment, fragmentactivity will be use?

Comment: @ Gem Ubaldo : Here `public class FragmentDoctor extends FragmentActivity` is wrong..You have to pass `Fragment` in this line ` fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();`

Comment: @GemUbaldo No, it'll be a fragment. A `FragmentActivity` is an `Activity` and not a `Fragment`.

Comment: @Gem Ubaldo : For more information how to create Fragments using `FragmentActivity` Please check this link -> http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/10/06/using-fragments-in-android-with-fragmentactivity/

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentDoctor` should extend from `Fragment` not from `FragmentActivity`
change this code

```
 public class FragmentDoctor extends FragmentActivity {
```

like this

```
 public class FragmentDoctor extends Fragment {
```

and

```
private void selectItemFragment(int position){

FragmentActivity fragment = null;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
switch(position) {
    default:
    case 0:
        fragment = new FragmentDoctor();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FragmentHospital();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new FragmentPharmacy();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new FragmentClinic();
        break;
}

if(fragment != null) {
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
   replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: yes it works but i cant configure the google map that i will attach in fragment if i use Fragment only

Comment: If you want to use FragmentActivity in one case .. you can use.. put condition like this before fragment transaction .. if(fragment != null ) { continue transaction } ..

Comment: change this line from `map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` to  `map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: after above changes .. what problems your facing.. tell me

Comment: i got confused on this if(fragment != null ) { continue transaction } where i will insert that?sorry im beginner only @RajaReddyPolamReddy

Comment: check my edit answer... if you want to use activity also instead of only fragments in any case you can use activity and start activity in that case using Intent.

Comment: still the fragment is error in  replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit(); @RajaReddyPolamReddy

Comment: show the full code .. along with imports also .. i think your imports are wrong.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy okay ill post the main activity

Comment: if i use fragment the google map shows but i cant customized it. btw the google map is in the fragment_doctor.xml @RajaReddyPolamReddy

Comment: here case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentDoctor();
            break; call activity instead of fragment .. using intent .. that will work

Comment: if those are a fragment it will work.. you have something wrong in that code ... i am unable to find what was the problem. difficult to tell what is the exact problem also.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy the problem is i cant configure the google map in fragment so i decided to use fragment activity but its error. when i use fragment, default google map only display only since i attach it in fragment_doctor.xml

Comment: that is the i told in first use activity for that one case and call the activity instead of fragment .. and put fragment check condition at that place.

Comment: i decided to use activity instead of fragment. btw thank you for helping me. and i decided to copy the drawer to other class so the menu navigation will not dissapear

Answer (score 0):

As below

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

FragmentActivity is part of support-v4 library..

So please add below dependency to your gradle file :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

You can also add this library by following below steps in Android Studio :

1. Select File
2. Select Project Structure
3. Select app
4. Select dependencies
5. Click on '+'
6. Select library dependency
7. Select support v4 library and
8. Press 'OK'

Edited :

```
public class FragmentDoctor extends FragmentActivity {
```

And also From your edited code I have noticed that you are extending `FragmentActivity` not `Fragment`.

So please follow below link for more information on How to create `Fragment` with `FragmentActivity` :

http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/10/06/using-fragments-in-android-with-fragmentactivity/

Thanks